# How to handle my JSON in rails to respond to ember in an update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, server

i need to create a correct respond from rails server but i dont know how.

this is the error that throws me

*"WARNING: Encountered "status" in payload, but no model was found for model name "status" (resolved model name using frontend@serializer:post:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("status"))"*

controller/posts/edit.js

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions:{
      submit: function(params){

        var self = this;

        this.store.findRecord('post', params).then(function(post){
          post.save();
          self.transitionToRoute('posts');
        });

        }
  }
});
```

this is the function in rails that it's hit when i save my post in ember

```
  def update

      post = Post.find(params[:id])

      if post.update(strong_params)
          render json: {status: "ok"}
      else
        render json: {status: "error"}
      end


  end
```

model/post.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr("string"),
  body: DS.attr("string")
});
```

So how i handle my json in rails to tell me when my posts could update or not

Note: The post is updated sucessfully but in my log console appear that message and i want to make it right

Comment: So your server is returning invalid JSON and we are supposed to guess why by looking at our crystal balls? Start by looking at the how the server responds and build up a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Believe or not your answer help me, i was watching the problem like the problem was ember only, so i need to reformulate my question

Comment: I'm guessing that you don't need to return any JSON. You should be able to use just `head :ok`. For the unsuccessful response you should return 422 unprocessable entity - `render json: { errors: @post.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity` .  This depends on the adapter used used in ember. But I would really recommend you make sure your application returns the correct HTTPs response codes.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your Ember serializer is currently the default `JSONAPISerializer`, which comes with strong opinions about what your JSON responses should look like. If instead you switch to a more basic serializer (such as the RESTSerializer), you'll probably stop seeing the error. More information available here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/models/customizing-serializers/

That said, part of the advantage to using Ember and Rails is that you can use a pre-built serialization layer that would simplify much of the data back and forth that is needed when working with an API. So it might be worth exploring those options too ...